# How can I make a regex match the entire string?

Tags: python, regex

Suppose I have a string like `test-123`.
I want to test whether it matches a pattern like `test-<number>`, where `<number>` means one or more digit symbols.

I tried this code:

```
import re
correct_string = 'test-251'
wrong_string = 'test-123x'
regex = re.compile(r'test-\d+')
if regex.match(correct_string):
    print 'Matching correct string.'
if regex.match(wrong_string):
    print 'Matching wrong_string.'
```

How can I make it so that only the `correct_string` matches, and the `wrong_string` doesn't? I tried using `.search` instead of `.match` but it didn't help.

Comment: similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173787/string-exact-match

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Try with specifying the start and end rules in your regex:

```
re.compile(r'^test-\d+$')
```

Comment: I see, thank you. Just after publication of my question I've found this mistake.

Comment: @smart really only needs to put the `$`, since `re.match` automatically assumes `^` on the regex.

Comment: @CDahn, I know. Ty!

Comment: Years using regex and I never knew what were the "^" and "+$". A greater explanation is in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34292024/regular-expression-vs-vs-none

Answer (score 27):

Since Python 3.4 you can use [re.fullmatch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.fullmatch) to avoid adding `^` and `$` to your pattern.

```
>>> import re
>>> p = re.compile(r'\d{3}')
>>> bool(p.match('1234'))
True

>>> bool(p.fullmatch('1234'))
False
```

Comment: This is the way to go, son! :)

Answer (score 26):

For exact match `regex = r'^(some-regex-here)$'`

^ : Start of string

$ : End of string

Answer (score 4):

I think It may help you -

```
import re
pattern = r"test-[0-9]+$"
s = input()

if re.match(pattern,s) :
    print('matched')
else :
    print('not matched')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try `re.findall()`:

```
import re
correct_string = 'test-251'

if len(re.findall("test-\d+", correct_string)) > 0:
    print "Match found"
```

Answer (score 0):

A pattern such as `\btest-\d+\b` should do you;

```
matches = re.search(r'\btest-\d+\', search_string)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/02O3dZ/2)

This requires the matching of word boundaries, so prevents other substrings from occuring after your desired match.