# Regular expression for YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS is not detecting the presence of .00Z

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have the following regular expression to match the date time format:

```
start_time = "1970-01-08T00:38:45"

regular_exp = '\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}'  

import re
if not re.match(regular_exp, start_time):
    print('error')
```

If I use the date/time: start_time = "1970-01-08T00:38:45:**00Z**"  <-- Note the **00Z**

the reguar expression is not detecting it.

How can I ensure I do not let the format with the 00Z is gettingn through?

Comment: You must add '^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$'   ^ for beginning of the string and $ for the end of the string. A more complete answer is here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45244813/how-can-i-make-a-regex-match-the-entire-string